# Scala: adding another field to json object from original

Tags: json, scala

I have this function that works:

```
def convertUsersToJsonOrig(lusers: Seq[User]): JsValue = {
    Json.toJson(
        lusers.map { u => Map("id" -> u.id, 
                              "firstName" -> u.firstName, 
                              "lastName" -> u.lastName, 
                              "mobile" -> u.mobile, 
                              "email" -> u.email, 
                              "username" -> u.username, 
                              "password" -> u.password)}
    )
```

}

However, I want to add a field like:

```
def convertUsersToJsonOrig(lusers: Seq[User]): JsValue = {
    Json.toJson(
        lusers.map { u => Map("id" -> u.id, 
                              "firstName" -> u.firstName, 
                              "lastName" -> u.lastName, 
                              "mobile" -> u.mobile, 
                              "email" -> u.email, 
                              "username" -> u.username, 
                              "password" -> u.password,
                              "rowNum"   -> 0
                      )}
    )
}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
No Json serializer found for type Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

rowNum is not a field of user.

Can something like this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The original `Map` is inferred to have type `Map[String, String]`, which `toJson` knows how to serialize.

But then you add a numeric value, so now the map becomes a `Map[String, Any]` in order to accommodate both numbers and strings. But `toJson` doesn't know how to handle an `Any`.

It'll work if you make the value be a string: `"rowNum" -> "0"`, but this is not necessarily what you want. I don't know which one you are using, but all JSON libraries provide wrapper classes for representing heterogeneous objects, something that should look like this:

```
val userJson: JsValue = JsObject(
  "firstName" -> JsString(u.firstName),
  "age"       -> JsNumber(u.age)
)
```

Comment: I tried "rowNum" -> JsNumber(0)  and "rowNum" -> "0" but get error message:
No Json serializer found for type Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Product with Serializable]]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga what JSON library are you using? My example is pseudocode, so it will probably not work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could not add that field in Scala. But, I was able to do that in ES6 using:

```
      $.extend(true, {}, {'rowNumber':i}, json_data [i])
```

where json_data has the array with all the objects coming from the server.